# EF Unidirectional One to Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an **IdentityUser** class which has a navigation property called **Logins** which is of type **Collection**.

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public IdentityUser(string userName);

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

In the **IdentityUserLogin** class there is a navigation property called **User** which is of type **IdentityUser**.

```
public class IdentityUserLogin
{
    public IdentityUserLogin();

    public virtual string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProviderKey { get; set; }
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

From this I can see that

1. the **IdentityUser** can have 0 to many **IdentityUserLogin**.
2. **IdentityUserLogin** must have a **IdentityUser**.

I tried:

```
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

but it was looking for a foreign key of **IdentityUser_Id** but it should be using **UserId** (which is a property of **IdentityUserLogin**

so then I tried:

```
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithMany(t => t.Logins)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);
```

but I get an error stating:

> IdentityUserLogin_User_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'IdentityUserLogin_User_Source' in relationship 'IdentityUserLogin_User'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Does anyone know how I can declare the relationship and specify the Foreign Key?

**Update 1**

This is my **IdentityUserLogin** map class:

```
public class IdentityUserLoginMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{
    public IdentityUserLoginMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.UserId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.LoginProvider)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.ProviderKey)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.UserId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("IdentityUserLogins");
        this.Property(t => t.LoginProvider).HasColumnName("LoginProvider");
        this.Property(t => t.ProviderKey).HasColumnName("ProviderKey");
        this.Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.User)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am setting a primary key

**Update 2**

Just to give a bit more of an explanation, here is the users table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IdentityUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.IdentityUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

and the **IdentityUserLogin** table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IdentityUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

but when I run my code on a new database I get this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IdentityUserLogins](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [IdentityUser_Id] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.IdentityUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

as you can see, the **IdentityUser_Id** is obsolete, it should be using the primary key.
That is my objective :)

Answer (score -1):

You might be confusing EF by not providing a Primary key property to your class `IdentityUserLogin`.
I think in this case EF is taking `UserId` as your primary key. Since primary key cannot be duplicate, and the relationship you are mapping says `WithMany` they conflict with each other.

**Update 1**

This is conflicting with your model:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.User).WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

because on class `IdentityUser` you have

```
public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
```

You need to use `WithMany(t => t.Logins)` in order to match your configuration with the model.

**Update 2**
This is a One-One relationship you need

```
public class IdentityUser
{
  ... 
  public virtual IdentityUserLogin Login { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

and

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.User).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Login);
```

Comment: I am setting a primary key, I have updated my post to show my mapping

Comment: But that's just the problem, you can't use UserId as the primary key and have a one-to-many relationship, because that would require the same key to be there twice.

Comment: Then this confirms my answer, you cannot say that `UserId` is unique and on the other side you tell EF that 1 `IdentityUser.Id` can exist multiple times in `IdentityUserLogin.UserId` if this is your primary key and you cannot have many.

Comment: A couple of things; There is no such method are ToMany I assume you mean WithMany which I tried (it is actually in the post). Also, incase you haven't noticed, both the classes are default .net identity classes and the relationship exists in the database, so unless I am missing something, they have UserId as the primary key and the foreign key, so it must be mappable.

Comment: Then you need to chance your ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins to IdentityUserLogin Login in your IdentityUser class

Comment: I can't change it. This is the class that ships with EF. It is designed to be a collection of IdentityUserLogin's so there must be a way to do this

Comment: What class is shipped with EF? None of your entities is shipped with EF. Your database model does not support having many IdentityUserLogin for every IdentityUser. You just showed your database structure. It cannot happen with your current db structure.

Comment: Then you need to define what approach you want to follow. If you want an `IdentityUser` to have many `IdentityUserLogin`s, the FK to `IdentityUser` cannot be your PK in `IdentityUserLogin` entity.